# How to count number of non empty elements in column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can i get the count of total non empty elements in a pandas column?

```
print(len(newDF.Paid_Off_In_Days).where(newDF.Paid_Off_In_Days != ''))
```

Data type is `int`
I get  error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'where'

```
  Paid_Off_In_Days        Credit_Amount
     1                       150
     15                      500
                             80
     18                      90
                             1200
     29                      600
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If empty means empty string compare for mask and use `sum` for count `True` values:

```
print((newDF.Paid_Off_In_Days != '').sum())
```

If empty means missing value use [`Series.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html):

```
print (newDF)
   Paid_Off_In_Days  col
0               1.0    a
1              15.0    s
2               NaN    d
3              18.0  NaN
4               NaN    f
5              29.0  NaN

print(newDF.Paid_Off_In_Days.count())
4
```

Comment: The problem is that some of the rows are empty in this column. ```sum()``` will count even the cells that are empty/whitespace.

Comment: @bibscy - so there are missing values and empty strings?

Comment: data type is ```int```  and there are missing values

Comment: Second solution console output: ```SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing```    https://imgur.com/YR2UmKx

Comment: @bibscy - Sorry, I add one `(` incorrect, need `print(newDF.Paid_Off_In_Days.count())`

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to check if the mean for females dataset based on condition where, but it's returning ```nan``` ```print(feamalesSamp.Paid_Off_In_Days.where((feamalesSamp.Paid_Off_In_Days > 100) & (feamalesSamp.Paid_Off_In_Days < 500)).mean())```

Comment: @bibscy - not sure, are data numeric? `print(feamalesSamp.Paid_Off_In_Days.dtypes)
`, because I test it with `feamalesSamp = pd.DataFrame({'Paid_Off_In_Days':[120,160,500, 800]})` and working correct.

Comment: ```Paid_Off_In_Days``` column contains integers.

Comment: @bibscy - hmm, if change treshold still not working?

Comment: The threshold was the mistake. It works. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer:

Code below uses regex to replace blanks with NaN. And pandas [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for non-NA cells.

```
# Import library
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
newDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'Paid_Off_In_Days':[1, np.nan, 15, '   ', 18, 29]   
})

# Regex to replace blanks with NaN
newDF = newDF.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

# Get counts
counts = newDF.count()
```

Output

```
print(counts)

Paid_Off_In_Days    4
dtype: int64
```